# post on face book's wall complex message programmatically using iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I've just solved the problem with posting on facebook's wall programmatically using Facebook iOS sdk. It is completely working in my application. Here's the part of code:

```
NSString *messageString=@"test message";
FBRequest *request=[[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession graphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:messageString forKey:@"message"] HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Now I need to post not only the text message on facebook's wall.
I need to post this:
[image: post on Facebook example]

Here are the parameters which I should use to make my post look similar http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/

Help me please to make tether values with parameters (message, link, caption etc.).

The very best answer would be `NSDictionary`object which I can pass to my `FBRequest`init method as a `parameters` argument.

Thanks you for your attention.

Comment: I could help you if you would use ShareKit, it supports several sharers, with images, texts and links. Easy to implement, free, safe.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use to post to Facebook for something very much like your picture.

```
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [SBJSON new];

NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            attachmentTitle, @"name",
                            attachmentLink, @"href",
                            attachmentCaption, @"caption",
                            attachmentDescription, @"description",
                            nil];

NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];

[postContent setObject:attachmentStr forKey:@"attachment"];       
[postContent setObject:textView.text forKey:@"message"];

[FB requestWithMethodName:@"stream.publish" andParams:postContent andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: That is an object you create using the Facebook SDK in generally in your AppDelegate.

Comment: Which tutorial did u follow? I find the fb developer site confuse when it comes to feedDialog (posting to wall).

Comment: I didn't follow a tutorial I figured it out on my own. What are you trying to do?